# Is it possible for PR and ROC curves for multiclass case to "turn back"?

Tags: r, statistics, roc

I have a problem with my ROC and PR curve.

I'm using JRip algorithm from RWeka package.
This is the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/student-alcohol-consumption/data
The goal is to find how does 'Dalc' attribute depend on other attributes.

I've been trying to get some nice PR and ROC curves to find the best parameters for the algorithm. However, my ROC and PR curves tend to "turn back" or jump more or less randomly.

The plots on the attached image show the ROC and PR curves. The parameter I am changing is number of folds (refer to https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/rules/JRip.html ). The numbers next to dots are values of the parameter F. Different colours are different classes. The Blue class is dominating and it's at quantity is at least 6 times more than all the other classes.

So is it possible that in this case the shape of the curves is correct? Should I just pick the point with the best (recall,precission) and the best (precision,fp_rate) for each class?

My method of drawing this curve:

inside loop:

- create classifier on training set
- with each iteration change one of its parameters
- try the classifier with predict() on validation set
- gather results, calculate true positive, false positive, true negative, flase - negative for every class (there are 5 classes)
- calculate precision, recall and false positive rate with formulas: precision = tp/tp+fp, recall = tp/tp+fn, fp rate = fp/tn+fp
- all the values for each class and every iteration are calculated seperately
- plot them

Maybe the formulas for true positive, true negative, etc. are incorrect?

On image:
left side: ROC curves, each graph has another parameter value added (incrementation)
right side: PR curves
colour: different classes
blue class: the most dominant

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSXo8.png)

While I was expecting something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LaYJ.png)

```
######### LEGEND #########
##### pred - vector of predicted classes by the model
##### tab - original data
##### class - class, one of 5
###########################

results_predykcji_true_false <- function(pred, tab)
{

  correct = vector(length=length(pred))
  for(i in 1:length(pred))
  {
    if(pred[i]==tab[i])
      correct[i]=1
    else
      correct[i]=0
  }

  return(correct)
}

### total amount of correct classifications
correct <- function(v)
{
  return(sum(v))
}

### total amount of incorrect classifications
incorrect <- function(v)
{
  return(length(v)-sum(v))
}

false_positive <- function(class, pred, tab)
{
  suma=0
  for(i in 1:length(tab))
  {
    if(pred[i] == class && tab[i] != class)
    {
      suma=suma+1
    }
  }
  return(suma)
}

false_negative <- function(class, pred, tab)
{
  suma=0
  for(i in 1:length(tab))
  {
    if(pred[i] != class && tab[i] == class)
    {
      suma=suma+1
    }
  }
  return(suma)
}

true_positive <- function(class, pred, tab)
{
  suma=0
  for(i in 1:length(tab))
  {
    if(pred[i] == class && tab[i] == class)
    {
      suma=suma+1
    }
  }
  return(suma)
}

true_negative <- function(class, pred, tab)
{
  suma=0
  for(i in 1:length(tab))
  {
    if(pred[i] != class && tab[i] != class)
    {
      suma=suma+1
    }
  }
  return(suma)
}

### precision
precyzja <- function(tab)
{
  ### removing NaN
  w1 <- tab$tp1/(tab$tp1 + tab$fp1)
  w2 <- tab$tp2/(tab$tp2 + tab$fp2)
  w3 <- tab$tp3/(tab$tp3 + tab$fp3)
  w4 <- tab$tp4/(tab$tp4 + tab$fp4)
  w5 <- tab$tp5/(tab$tp5 + tab$fp5)

  w1[is.na(w1)] <- 1
  w2[is.na(w2)] <- 1
  w3[is.na(w3)] <- 1
  w4[is.na(w4)] <- 1
  w5[is.na(w5)] <- 1

  return(cbind(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5))
}

### recall (true positive rate)
odzysk <- function(tab)
{
  w1 <- tab$tp1/(tab$tp1 + tab$fn1)
  w2 <- tab$tp2/(tab$tp2 + tab$fn2)
  w3 <- tab$tp3/(tab$tp3 + tab$fn3)
  w4 <- tab$tp4/(tab$tp4 + tab$fn4)
  w5 <- tab$tp5/(tab$tp5 + tab$fn5)

  return(cbind(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5))
}

### false positive rate
fp_rate <- function(tab)
{
  w1 <- tab$fp1/(tab$tn1 + tab$fp1)
  w2 <- tab$fp2/(tab$tn2 + tab$fp2)
  w3 <- tab$fp3/(tab$tn3 + tab$fp3)
  w4 <- tab$fp4/(tab$tn4 + tab$fp4)
  w5 <- tab$fp5/(tab$tn5 + tab$fp5)

  return(cbind(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5))
}

### this function is suppoused to return data table with outcomes for every class
statistics_without_plots <- function(pred, tab)
{
  results <- data.table::data.table()

  k1 <- true_positive(1, pred, tab)
  k2 <- true_positive(2, pred, tab)
  k3 <- true_positive(3, pred, tab)
  k4 <- true_positive(4, pred, tab)
  k5 <- true_positive(5, pred, tab)

  results$tp1 <- k1
  results$tp2 <- k2
  results$tp3 <- k3
  results$tp4 <- k4
  results$tp5 <- k5

  k1 <- false_positive(1, pred, tab)
  k2 <- false_positive(2, pred, tab)
  k3 <- false_positive(3, pred, tab)
  k4 <- false_positive(4, pred, tab)
  k5 <- false_positive(5, pred, tab)

  results$fp1 <- k1
  results$fp2 <- k2
  results$fp3 <- k3
  results$fp4 <- k4
  results$fp5 <- k5

  k1 <- false_negative(1, pred, tab)
  k2 <- false_negative(2, pred, tab)
  k3 <- false_negative(3, pred, tab)
  k4 <- false_negative(4, pred, tab)
  k5 <- false_negative(5, pred, tab)

  results$fn1 <- k1
  results$fn2 <- k2
  results$fn3 <- k3
  results$fn4 <- k4
  results$fn5 <- k5

  k1 <- true_negative(1, pred, tab)
  k2 <- true_negative(2, pred, tab)
  k3 <- true_negative(3, pred, tab)
  k4 <- true_negative(4, pred, tab)
  k5 <- true_negative(5, pred, tab)

  results$tn1 <- k1
  results$tn2 <- k2
  results$tn3 <- k3
  results$tn4 <- k4
  results$tn5 <- k5

  return(results)
}

### summary data table, you can ignore this one
summary <- function(classifier, tab1, vec1)
{
  is_correct_vec <- results_predykcji_true_false(predict(classifier, tab1),vec1)

  r = data.table::data.table(
    algorytm_i_parametry = toString(classifier$call),
    reguly = classifier$classifier$toString(),
    tp = correct(is_correct_vec),
    fp = incorrect(is_correct_vec)
  )
  message("")
  message("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  message("/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////")
  message("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  message("")
  message(paste("algorytm i parametry:", r$algorytm_i_parametry))
  cat(r$reguly)
  message(paste("odgadniete:", r$tp))
  message(paste("nieodgadniete:", r$fp))

  return(r)
}

### return weka_control with changed parameter
zwroc_weka_control_zmien_parametr <- function(parametr,seed,prune,method,iteration)
{
  if(method == "silnia") ### factorial
    wartosc <- factorial(iteration)
  if(method == "kwadrat") ### squared
    wartosc <- iteration^2
  if(method == "inkrementacja") ### incrementation
    wartosc <- iteration

  if(parametr == 'F')
    return(Weka_control(F = wartosc, S=seed, P=prune))

  if(parametr == 'N')
    return(Weka_control(N = wartosc, S=seed, P=prune))

  if(parametr == 'S')
    return(Weka_control(S = wartosc, P=prune))
}

### draw roc/pr curve
curve_roc_pr <- function(x,y,xlab,ylab,main,labels)
{
  plot(x$w1,y$w1,ylim=c(0,1.1),xlim=c(0,1.1),type="l",col="blue", bty="n",xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,main=main)
  points(x$w1,y$w1,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),col="blue",pch=19,cex=0.7)
  text(x$w1,y$w1,labels=labels, cex= 1, pos=3,col="blue")

  points(x$w2,y$w2,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),type="l",col="red")
  points(x$w2,y$w2,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),col="red",pch=19,cex=0.7)
  text(x$w2,y$w2,labels=labels, cex= 1, pos=3,col="red")

  points(x$w3,y$w3,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),type="l",col="purple")
  points(x$w3,y$w3,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),col="purple",pch=19,cex=0.7)
  text(x$w3,y$w3,labels=labels, cex= 1, pos=3,col="purple")

  points(x$w4,y$w4,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),type="l",col="green")
  points(x$w4,y$w4,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),col="green",pch=19,cex=0.7)
  text(x$w4,y$w4,labels=labels, cex= 1, pos=3,col="green")

  points(x$w5,y$w5,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),type="l",col="orange")
  points(x$w5,y$w5,ylim=c(0,1.0),xlim=c(0,1.0),col="orange",pch=19,cex=0.7)
  text(x$w5,y$w5,labels=labels, cex= 1, pos=3,col="orange")

  # legend("bottom",
  #        c("1","2","3","4","5"),
  #        fill = c("blue","red","purple","green","orange"))
}

jrip_roc <- function(training_set,validation_set,parametr,seed,prune,method,iterations,curve)
{   
  results <- data.table::data.table()
  tp_fp_tn_fn <- data.table::data.table()


  labels <- vector()

  for(i in 1:iterations)
  {
    if(method=="silnia") ### factorial
      labels[i]<-factorial(i) 
    if(method=="kwadrat") ### squared
      labels[i]<-(i^2)
    if(method=="inkrementacja") ### incrementation
      labels[i]<-(i)

    ##### return weka_Control with changes parameter for this iteration
    ctrl <- zwroc_weka_control_zmien_parametr(parametr,seed,prune,method,i)
    message(ctrl)

    ##### create classification model
    classifier <- JRip(Dalc ~ ., training_set, control=ctrl)

    ##### store results from this iteration into data table
    results<-rbind(results,summary(classifier, validation_set, validation_set$Dalc))

    preds <- predict(classifier, validation_set, type="class")
    ##### store results (true positive, true negative, false positive, false negative)
    tp_fp_tn_fn <- rbind(tp_fp_tn_fn,statistics_without_plots(preds, validation_set$Dalc))
  }

  results <- cbind(results,tp_fp_tn_fn)

  if(curve=="roc")
  {
    x <- data.table::data.table(fp_rate(results))
    y <- data.table::data.table(odzysk(results))

    xlab="FP rate"
    ylab="Odzysk"
    main=paste("curve ROC\n zmienna -",parametr,", P = ",prune)
  }

  if(curve=="pr")
  {
    x <- data.table::data.table(odzysk(results))
    y <- data.table::data.table(precyzja(results))

    xlab="Odzysk"
    ylab="Precyzja"
    main=paste("curve PR\n zmienna -",parametr,", P = ",prune)
  }

  curve_roc_pr(x,y,xlab,ylab,main,labels)

  return(results)
}

### discretization of data
d12<-zdyskretyzuj(t12)

### division into validation and training set
ulamek = 3/4

d12_train <- slice(d12,1:(ulamek*(nrow(d12))))
d12_test <- slice(d12,(ulamek*nrow(d12)):nrow(d12))

par(mfrow=c(3,2))
jrip_roc(d12_train, d12_test, "F", 0, FALSE, "inkrementacja", 3, "roc")
jrip_roc(d12_train, d12_test, "F", 0, FALSE, "inkrementacja", 3, "pr")
jrip_roc(d12_train, d12_test, "F", 0, FALSE, "inkrementacja", 5, "roc")
jrip_roc(d12_train, d12_test, "F", 0, FALSE, "inkrementacja", 5, "pr")
jrip_roc(d12_train, d12_test, "F", 0, FALSE, "inkrementacja", 7, "roc")
jrip_roc(d12_train, d12_test, "F", 0, FALSE, "inkrementacja", 7, "pr")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: These curves aren't ROC curves or PR curves. How did you generate them? Please add the code you use to generate them so we can help you find out the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have updated the post with the code and my method of drawing the curves